# Build a WS with Spring

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, java-web-start, spring-3

I need to create a WS with Spring 3.0.4.RELEASE to run in a Tomcat with Axis2. I'm following this doc: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#remoting-web-services-jaxws-export-ri (if that paragraph can be called "doc")

Ok, here are the details:

The java class:

```
package foo;
@WebService(serviceName="MyService")
public class MyService{
  @WebMethod  
  public String getString(){
    return "Hello StackOverflow";
  }  
}
```

The WEB-INF/spring-ws.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd  
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd">

  <wss:binding url="/myService" service="#myService" />

  <ws:service id="myService"
    impl="foo.MyService" />

</beans>
```

The WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="myService" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>my Service</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-ws.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- this is for Spring -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- these are for JAX-WS -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jaxws-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jaxws-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And last, but not less important, the **error** when I **start tomcat 6.0.29**:

```
Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-ws.xml]
```

Someone has any clue of what is happening? Is all the configuration correct? Does anyone have a simple (working) WS to show how to deploy a WS using Spring?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also experience this issue a while back and figured out the problem is with the "https://". Change it back to http:// and you should be good to go. But when you use http:// you get a schema validation error in eclipse because eclipse can't automatically redirect schema url from http:// to https://. And apparently netbeans is capable of it.

One more thing. You'll have to have the xbeans-spring as well. I honestly think that's a pretty stupid dependency.